# SOAP parsing in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, soap

I created a SOAP client in PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxxx.net/Service/Service.svc?wsdl");
$response= $client->GetHotelNugget($data);
```

But I can't parse the response. I need `<a:TITLE>` tag value.

Output of the SOAP client:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetHotelNuggetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetHotelNuggetResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:HotelNugget>
               <a:NUGGETNAME>Yaz Tatili Otelleri</a:NUGGETNAME>
               <a:NUGGETORDER>10</a:NUGGETORDER>
               <a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>AS_SOL_UST</a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>
               <a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>yaz-tatili-otelleri</a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>
               <a:TITLE>Yaz Tatili Otelleri</a:TITLE>
               <a:UNIQUECODE>YTOTL</a:UNIQUECODE>
               <a:WEBNUGGETID>306</a:WEBNUGGETID>
            </a:HotelNugget>
            <a:HotelNugget>
               <a:NUGGETNAME>Ramazan Fırsatları</a:NUGGETNAME>
               <a:NUGGETORDER>20</a:NUGGETORDER>
               <a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>AS_SOL_UST</a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>
               <a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>ramazan-firsatlari</a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>
               <a:TITLE>Ramazan Fırsatları</a:TITLE>
               <a:UNIQUECODE>RFIR</a:UNIQUECODE>
               <a:WEBNUGGETID>308</a:WEBNUGGETID>
            </a:HotelNugget>
            <a:HotelNugget>
               <a:NUGGETNAME>Ramazan Bayramı Otelleri</a:NUGGETNAME>
               <a:NUGGETORDER>30</a:NUGGETORDER>
               <a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>AS_SOL_UST</a:PARENTUNIQUECODE>
               <a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>ramazan-bayrami-otelleri</a:REWRITENUGGETNAME>
               <a:TITLE>Ramazan Bayramı Otelleri</a:TITLE>
               <a:UNIQUECODE>RBO</a:UNIQUECODE>
               <a:WEBNUGGETID>283</a:WEBNUGGETID>
            </a:HotelNugget>       
         </GetHotelNuggetResult>
      </GetHotelNuggetResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: This looks like the XML output. What do you get for `var_dump($response)`?

Comment: var_dump return is ; object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetHotelNuggetResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (0) { } }

Comment: Probably `GetHotelNuggetResult` is missing in the WSDL definition? http://tempuri.org/ is not saying much as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check the `print_r` value

```
$xmlResp = simplexml_load_string($response);
$jsonResp = json_encode($xmlResp);
$arrResp = json_decode($jsonResp);

foreach($arrResp as $k=>$v) {
    print_r($v);
}
```

You can then access the TITLE tag inside foreach by something like below

`$v['HotelNugget']['TITLE'];`

Comment: error:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string